# How to perform "RXJava 2 queue jobs" until value changes?

Tags: android, sockets, rx-java2

I'm using RXJava2 in my Android app, and I have a somewhat peculiar scenario.
I want to perform unknown amount of jobs (determined by the user), but I want them to start only after a certain value has changed.

My specific requirement is to use a Socket for server communication,
and the flow is the following:

1. User requests some data - data is retrieved by sending data to the socket and wait for the response.
2. The module that communicates with the server should open a Socket connection, and only after the connection established, it may fetch the requested data.
3. While Socket attempt to connect, the user may request some more data.
4. After the connection established successfully the module should perform all the requests sent by the user while connection process was in progress.
5. The module also should publish the results that came for each data sent to the socket.

How can this be accomplished using RXJava2?

Comment: show us the code, what do you have so far?

Comment: I don't have a code sample at the moment, as I try to understand how to tackle the issue. I'm relatively new to RX Java so I don't really know how to make several calls to wait for the completion of another one - the one announcing the Socket is connected :(

Answer (score 3):

You could use an `UnicastSubject` for the queue part and do some `flatMap`-ping once the connection is established:

```
UnicastSubject<String> userRequests = new UnicastSubject.create();

Single.fromCallable(() -> new Socket("server", port))
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .flatMapObservable(socket -> {

      InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
      OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
      byte[] responseBuffer = new byte[4096];

      return userRequests
         .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
         .map(request -> {

             out.write(request.getBytes());

             int n = in.read(responseBuffer);
             if (n >= 0) {
                 return new String(responseBuffer, 0, n);
             }

             throw new IOException("Socket closed while waiting for response");
         })
         .doFinally(() -> socket.close());
  });
```

Since you are working on the Socket level, it is your responsibility to work out the proper encoding of the requests to be written and the proper decoding of the response to be read (i.e., how long (in bytes) the response is to a particular request).

Comment: Thanks, this looks like what I was looking for. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Het akarnokd, I didn't really understand how to work with the "UnicastSubject". How can I add jobs to it?

Comment: What's the type of your job?

Comment: NM. Found it. Just had to call requests.onNext to add a job

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would need `FlowableTransformers.valve()` for this, from [RxJava2Extensions](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions).

It should work something like this

```
    PublishSubject<String> jobs = PublishSubject.create().toSerialized();

    BehaviorSubject<Boolean> isConnected = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(false);

    CompositeDisposable disposables = new CompositeDisposable();

    public void connect() {
        disposables.add(socketService.subscribe((success) -> {
            isConnected = true;
        }));
    }

    public void addJob(String job) {
        jobs.onNext(job);
    }

    public void executeQueuedTasks() {
       disposables.add(jobs
          .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
          .compose(FlowableTransformers.valve(isConnected))
          .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<>() {
              ...
          })
       );
    }

    public void destroy() {
        disposables.clear();
    }
}
```

But the `UnicastSubject` sample above is more likely to work, I wrote this off the top of my head.